# Dojo data-dojo-props won't bind to model when it's inside a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

After some first steps with dojo I managed to have a `var model;` and bind it to an input with dojo with

```
require(["dojo/parser"],
  function (parser) {
    model = { myValue:null };
    parser.parse();
  }
);
```

In my .jsp I have some input with `data-dojo-props = "value: at(model, 'myValue')"`. The `myValue` gets filled with the value from the input.

Now I tried to have that model inside an object.

```
function MyObject() {
  var self = this;
  this.model;
  require(["dojo/parser"],
    function (parser) {
      self.model = { myValue:null };
      parser.parse();
    }
  );
}
```

In my .jsp I have a `myObject = new MyObject();` and the input changed to `data-dojo-props = "value: at(self.model, 'myValue')"` (when I tried to write `myObject.model`, dojo complained, that `myObject` is undefined, so I guess the scope of the require/binding stuff is from where it is declared - so `self.myValue` seems to be the right thing in `data-dojo-props`).

My Problem: after I moved the `model` inside `MyObject` the values of the input won't bind to `myValue` anymore.

What am I doing wrong - or is it even impossible what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not far away ... - you have to tell dojo more explicitely where the model is - the way for me is to use the `propsThis` argument in `parser.parse()`.

```
function MyObject() {
  var self = this;
  this.model;
  require(["dojo/parser"],
    function (parser) {
      self.model = { myValue:null };
      parser.parse(propsThis: self);
    }
  );
}
```

And the input has a `data-dojo-props = "value: at(this.model, 'myValue')"`.